# PHPExcel throwing error, locale? Not using locale

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to use PHPExcel, and it's throwing an error for even the most basic things, and even for a script copied from somewhere ( http://blog.clock.co.uk/phpexcel-example/ ).

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/.../public_html/pear/PEAR/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Calculation.php</b> on line <b>1685</b><br />
```

The outputted file has this as the very top of the file, for which Excel (or Open Office) says is not a valid file. If I remove those two lines, everything is fine and Excel (or OO) can open it with no problems and everything the script does is there.

Calculation.php line 1685:

```
foreach (glob($localeFileDirectory.'/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
```

And the function it is in:

```
private function __construct() {
$localeFileDirectory = PHPEXCEL_ROOT.'PHPExcel/locale/';
foreach (glob($localeFileDirectory.'/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
    $filename = substr($filename,strlen($localeFileDirectory)+1);
    if ($filename != 'en') {
        self::$_validLocaleLanguages[] = $filename;
    }
}

$setPrecision = (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? 12 : 16;
$this->_savedPrecision = ini_get('precision');
if ($this->_savedPrecision < $setPrecision) {
    ini_set('precision',$setPrecision);
}
}   //  function __construct()
```

I installed PHPExcel via PEAR.

I didn't see a "locale" directory anywhere in the PHPExcel setup, so I tried creating it but still have the same problem.

I'm not setting or using a locale feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear then that there is a problem in the PEAR installation of PHPExcel, which I'll need to investigate.

You can find the locale directory and files in the source repository on github (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/master/Classes) or in the standard zip distributions; but it would probably be better to use the full zip installation in case there are any other problems with the PEAR instal

Comment: That did the trick. I downloaded the PHPExcel 1.7.8 - PEAR (from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/96183 ) and just overwrote the entire PEAR installation on the server and it now works. It seems the locale directory is simply missing from the PEAR package I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem in PHP 5.3 + PHPExcelv1.7.6(2011-02-27) .
I solved this by updating to **PHPExcel v1.8.0(2014-03-02)**